# using dll that creates array to use in c#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, dll

I want to make a dll using c++ which has a function that creates a .bmp image by creating an array using c++ `new`, filling it, and then returning the pointer.
I want to use this function in a c# project but then how do I delete this array after using it?

do I create another function in my dll that receives a pointer and `delete[]` it?

or is there a way to directly delete the array in c#?

or c# automatically deletes it when it goes out of scope?

Comment: You'll have to export a function that lets you delete it again.  Otherwise very common in C-style interfaces, that's what a *handle* is all about.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create another function to delete the pointer. C# won't automatically delete it when it goes out of scope and there are some methods Microsoft exposes to delete objects but they're for windows handles. E.x.: Marshal.FreeHGlobal.

Answer (score 0):

C# (.NET) does not automatically delete the pointer (release the allocated memory) if your dll contains [`unmanaged code`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e91td57%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Releasing unmanaged resources is your responsibility (.NET can do it behind the scenes for you if itself create and use any unmanaged resource, but your case is not the same). However, even if you manually release these resources (allocated memory in your case), you should consider supplying custom methods in your dll instead of calling delete directly in the caller part. Mixing different CRT versions and environments is not a good practice. To see why please visit this [link](http://siomsystems.com/mixing-visual-studio-versions/). It is better to write custom allocater/deallocater in your dll and use them for object management.